# Hardness of a variant of the CDH problem

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, hardness-assumptions

Given $g$, a generator of a multiplicative group (over some finite field or elliptic curve), and the group elements $\left( g^x, g^a, g^b, g^c, g^{x(a+b)}, g^{x(b+c)} \right)$, is possible to efficiently find the value of $g^{x(a+b+c)}$ (without knowledge of the values $x, a, b, c$)?

I believe the problem at hand is closely related to the CDH problem (given $\left (g, g^a, g^b \right)$, find $g^{ab}$). An efficient algorithm of CDH immediately leads to an efficient algorithm for the above problem. So the above problem is at least not harder than CDH. However, I neither found a way to use additional information to arrive at an efficient solution nor was I able show that it is in fact as hard as CDH. So any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let suppose $\mathcal{B}$ knows how to compute $g^{x(a+b+c)}$, and I want to solve the cdh challenge $(g,X,Y)$, (we will interpret $X$ as $g^x$ and $Y$ as $g^b$) we choose scalars $d,e$ which correspond to $(a+b)$ and $(b+c)$ and we compute
$Z=\mathcal{B}(X, g^d\cdot Y^{-1}, Y, g^e\cdot Y^{-1},X^d, X^e )$.

We return $\frac{X^{d+e}}{Z}$.

Proof: $DLog \left(\frac{X^{d+e}}{Z}\right) = DLog \left(X^{d+e}\right) - DLog \left(Z\right) =  x(d+e)- x\left( d-b + b + e-b\right) = xb$.

Comment: Sad to see the problem is actually not easier than CDH, there would have been some nice applications otherwise. It took me a while to work through your post. Fascinating how you came up with this so quickly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @raisyn Why are you sad, if this problem is harder, it means you can use it as an hardness assumption for your applications. No?

Comment: Well in the application I had in mind (related to aggregate signatures) I needed it the other way around. If is would be possible, there would be have been a nice way to aggregate signature efficiently in a specific setting.

Comment: @raisyn I advise the reading of 
"The Uber-Assumption Family" (Boyen) to have an intuition to characterize the hard problems in a group context (even you do not find any reduction to standard assumption).